# How to get updated app on reload in Figwheel?

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

Using Figwheel with cljs projects gives me unreliable caching. Sometimes saving the project doesn't load Figwheel, and then if I refresh the page, instead of loading the latest version of the app, it takes me to an earlier cached version of the app. How can I make caching more reliable in Figwheel, so that when I reload, I'm at the latest version of the app and not the old version?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example showing the problem.

Comment: My guess is, that your JS code is borked (see the dev console for errors) and things just break.  Also since there are caches involved in building cljs, its usually a good idea to clean the project, if the WTF become to many.

Answer (score 0):

With Figwheel there are certain ways to structure your code to make it "reloadable". Your caching problems sound much like some internal state persists between changes. Check the documentation here for some tips: https://figwheel.org/docs/reloadable_code.html